# how to filter repeated rows based on date in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables

table 1 name : **depot_tracking**

```
     -------------------------------------------------
    depot_tracking_id | cont_details_id |    date    |
    -------------------------------------------------
           1          |       4         | 05-02-2015 |
           2          |       1         | 25-03-2015 |
           3          |       3         | 05-04-2015 |
           4          |       2         | 15-02-2015 |
           5          |       3         | 05-05-2015 |
           6          |       2         | 23-03-2015 |
           7          |       1         | 15-05-2015 |
    --------------------------------------------------
```

second table name : **cont_details**

```
      -----------------------------------
          cont_no      | cont_details_id | 
       -----------------------------------
           aa          |       1         |
           bb          |       2         |
           cc          |       3         |
           dd          |       4         | 
           ee          |       5         |
           ff          |       6         |
           gg          |       7         |
    --------------------------------------
```

now i want to merge this two tables and filter repeated rows and one more most important thing is i have to filter the rows which has OLDER dates. This is what exactly i am expecting output

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------
    depot_tracking_id | cont_details_id |    date    | cont_no
    ----------------------------------------------------------
           1          |       4         | 05-02-2015 |  dd
           5          |       3         | 05-05-2015 |  cc
           6          |       2         | 23-03-2015 |  bb
           7          |       1         | 15-05-2015 |  aa
    ---------------------------------------------------------
```

please some one help me to filter repeated rows ( filter the rows which has old date rows) thanks

```
ORDER BY (str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')) DESC LIMIT 1
```

by using this code i can change date column (DD-MM-YYYY) to mysql format date

but dont dont know how to filter repeated rows based on dates

Comment: Note that dates in sql adhere to a specific format. This isn't it. Fix that then get back to us.

Comment: is there any particular reason you want to do this with a left join rather than aggregation?

Comment: Your expected results don't match up with what you're saying. You said `OLDER` dates, but for cont_details_id 3 you take date 05-05-2015 and not 05-04-2015. Both of which are in incorrect format, as Strawberry mentioned, which is probably part of the confusion.

Comment: @McAdam331 your edit has changed the meaning of the question - filtering the older dates is filtering OUT the older dates - which is easily intuited by looking at the expected result, which has the LATER date and tracking_id for each `cont_details_id`. If you filter sediment from water - you want the water, not the sediment. same concept applies. Please try and refrain from forcing your own interpretation into a question.

Comment: @pala_ without the OP's clarification, there's no indication that what you think is any more correct than the way I interpreted the question. The question was written in a way that, to me, contradicted the expected results, but I did not change the expected results because I was not sure what they wanted. Also, was that worth downvoting an answer that can be modified so simply to give the expected results?

Comment: It may have been more clear if they said 'filter older dates *from* the results' but they didn't.

Comment: @McAdam331 as you say - you found the meaning unclear - yet you chose to change the fundamental premise of the question, rather than wait for clarification from the OP, leaving a six hour period where the meaning of the question was in all probability the exact opposite of what the OP intended.  Even if your interpretation is correct - it's still not right to remove ambiguity like that without clarification from the question asker. As for the clarity - the expected results were consistently the max date - this is sufficient (in my mind) to clarify the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all of your field values can be reliably determined by using aggregate functions, you only need a simple aggregation query.

```
select max(d.depot_tracking_id), c.cont_details_id, max(d.date), c.cont_no
  from depot_tracking d
    inner join cont_details c
      on c.cont_details_id = d.cont_details_id
  group by c.cont_details_id
```

In order for this to work, your date fields have to be an actual date type, not a string type. or if they ARE a string type, they need to be 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, not 'dd-mm-yyyy'.

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f05a/2)

**update**

Since it seems you are stuck using the broken date format - this query will work:

```
select max(d.depot_tracking_id), c.cont_details_id, max(str_to_date(d.date,'%d-%m-%Y')), c.cont_no
  from depot_tracking d
    inner join cont_details c
      on c.cont_details_id = d.cont_details_id
  group by c.cont_details_id
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32dae/1)

Comment: (str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')) i used this query to change date from string to date format. @pala_

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/113ed/1

```
SELECT 
d.depot_tracking_id,
c.cont_details_id,
d.`date`,
c.cont_no
FROM depot_tracking d
LEFT JOIN depot_tracking d1
ON d.cont_details_id = d1.cont_details_id
  AND d.`date` < d1.`date`
LEFT JOIN cont_details c
ON c.cont_details_id = d.cont_details_id
WHERE d1.`date` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, MySQL does not store dates in the 'dd-mm-yyyy' format but in 'yyyy-mm-dd'. If you are using a `date` type, the following solution will work. If it's not, you'll have to do some string to date formatting. I highly recommend you change to store dates the proper way though.

Start by selecting the newest date for each `cont_details_id` in the `depot_tracking` table like this:

```
SELECT cont_details_id, MAX(date) AS latest
FROM depot_tracking
GROUP BY cont_details_id;
```

Once you have that, you can join it back to your original tables using date/cont_details_id to get the rows you want:

```
SELECT d.depot_tracking_id, d.cont_details_id, d.date, c.cont_no
FROM depot_tracking d
JOIN(
  SELECT cont_details_id, MAX(date) AS latestDate
  FROM depot_tracking
  GROUP BY cont_details_id) tmp ON tmp.cont_details_id = d.cont_details_id AND tmp.latestDate = d.date
JOIN cont_details c ON c.cont_details_id = tmp.cont_details_id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9985/4) example that shows both queries separately so you can see how they come together.