# how to filter repeated rows using DATE in Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

i have 4 tables and i am using LEFT JOIN to merge the tables and all work fine.

This is the query i am using

```
   SELECT cont_details.* FROM depot_tracking
   LEFT JOIN depot_details
   ON depot_tracking.depot_details_id = depot_details.depot_details_id
   LEFT JOIN cont_details 
   ON depot_tracking.cont_details_id = cont_details.cont_no
   WHERE depot_details.depot_city = "maa"
   AND depot_tracking.status = "0" AND depot_tracking.gate_out =""
```

and now i am getting out like this !

```
--------------------------------------------
 cont_details_id  |    gate_in  | cont_no
--------------------------------------------
       1          | 05-05-2015  |  dd
       1          | 13-04-2015  |  cc
       2          | 23-03-2015  |  bb
       3          | 15-05-2015  |  aa
       1          | 21-02-2015  |  dd
       3          | 25-05-2015  |  cc
       2          | 30-03-2015  |  bb
       4          | 15-05-2015  |  aa
```

now i want to filter repeated rows based on `depot_tracking.gate_in` column.

in this image there is con_details_id (1) come two time now i want  19-04-2015 (last date) maximum date only , rest has to be filter, same to all 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 ,etc..,

the problem is i can't change gate_in column to date format so i used to change the column to STRING TO DATE FORMATE Using this below query

```
(str_to_date(d.gate_in,'%d-%m-%Y'))
```

so please someone help me to filter repeated rows (only show maximum date rows )

Expecting output is now

```
--------------------------------------------
 cont_details_id  |    gate_in  | cont_no
--------------------------------------------
       1          | 05-05-2015  |  dd
       3          | 25-05-2015  |  cc
       2          | 30-03-2015  |  bb
       4          | 15-05-2015  |  aa
```

Comment: Fix the date issue, or stop using sql for this.

Comment: How is it that two 'different' accounts, happen to have the same query, about the same data, in identically named tables, with identically malformed dates, within 24 hours of each other? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105515/how-to-filter-repeated-rows-based-on-date-in-mysql/30105782?noredirect=1#comment48343224_30105782

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just order your table then group by id

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      table1
    ORDER BY
      cont_details_id ASC, gate_in DESC
  ) origin
GROUP BY
  origin.cont_details_id
```

Replace `table1` with your result now

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b90d5/1/0

Comment: how it works :O Thanks a Lot :) my two days headache u just cleared :D

Comment: this answer is fundamentally broken, and while it may appear to work - it's just happy coincidence. you cannot rely on mysql to select the correct values when you choose fields that aren't present in the `group by`, nor used in aggregate functions.